# Is there a 1-categorical treatment of operadic left Kan extensions in the literature?

Tags: ct.category-theory, operads, higher-algebra

[Lurie develops in Section 3.1.2 of Higher Algebra](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/papers/HA.pdf#page=329) a notion of operadic left Kan extension used to compute free algebras, giving a left adjoint $\mathrm{Alg}_{\mathcal{O}}(\mathcal{C})\to\mathrm{Alg}_{\mathcal{O}'}(\mathcal{C})$ to the forgetful functor $\mathrm{Alg}_{\mathcal{O}}(\mathcal{C})\to\mathrm{Alg}_{\mathcal{O}'}(\mathcal{C})$ associated to any map of $\infty$-operads $\mathcal{O}\to\mathcal{O}'$.

There's a number of constructions in the $1$-categorical setting that resemble this notion a bit, including [monoidal Kan extensions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/205838) (see also [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00339331/en/), [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04911), [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.6994), [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.10481), and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364575/left-kan-extensions-of-strong-monoidal-functors)) and [multicategorical Kan extensions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161912/multi-categorical-left-kan-extensions). However, (as far as I understand) these don't quite capture the general notion developed by Lurie.

Is there a detailed treatment specifically for $1$-categorical operadic left Kan extensions somewhere in the categorical literature?

Comment: What do you mean by detailed treatment? What do you expect? This 'extension of scalars' function along an operad morphism appears in tons of papers.

Comment: @FernandoMuro I didn't know that "extension of scalars" was the proper name for the $1$-categorical version of the notion, thanks! I'll read more about these, and in a few days I'll reformulate this question into a proper one :)

Comment: This operation is used pretty much everywhere in operads, see, for example, Theorem 8.10 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.5675v3, which includes background and references.

Comment: @emily 'extensión of scalars' is not the proper name, it's just how I think of it in comparison with the case of rings. I hope you don't mind me saying but it looks like if you're reading the literature backwards.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Thanks, Dmitri! Your paper is super helpful! (And cool/interesting, too! :)

Comment: @FernandoMuro Oh I don't mind, this is roughly the case: I don't understand $\infty$-operadic Kan extensions, and really was trying to figure out where in the literature I could read more about them, starting from the classical/$1$-categorical situation first.

Comment: (To be more detailed: I recently became interested in some [generalised notions of graded rings](https://mathoverflow.net/q/403448), a setting in which there's a natural "change of grading" adjunction coming from "monoidal left Kan extensions". Before this, I had came upon a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/205838) by Martin Brandenburg whose [most voted answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/210088) mentioned operadic Kan extensions, and thus I was trying to figure out where to start learning about these things, as the literature on "monoidal left Kan extensions" is rather small.)

Comment: @emily the definition is very simple: $\mathcal{O}'\circ_{\mathcal{O}}A$ for any $\mathcal{O}$-algebra $A$. Carrying out explicit computations is much more difficult, though.